# Perception of "luck" in terms of positive/negative aspect, improbability pattern and scale in different languages

Tags: semantics, list-of-languages, meaning

I am interested in how concept of luck is expressed in different languages. As far as I know, in most Indo-European languages, there are similar ways to express the concept of *luck* and situations around it. I am going to provide some examples known to me, primarily, in English. I would be grateful for the examples in other languages or corrections of my mistakes.

**1. Negative/positive aspect**

Common semantics:

noun *luck* - positive improbability

negation of noun *luck* - negative improbability

adj *lucky* - positive result of improbability

negation of adj *lucky* = *unlucky* - negative result of improbability

In English:
In collocations *bad luck* and *good luck*, the word *luck* itself does not seem to carry negative or positive aspect to it and just expresses improbability.
However:
*He got to where he is today with a lot of luck.* implies positive results from positive improbable events.

What about other languages? Do you know other languages besides English, where *luck* does not imply positive occurrence? Can it also be inconsistent like in English? Does negation of *luck* always transforms improbability from positive to negative, or can it rather neutralize positivity, so *unlucky* = mundane, uneventful?

**2. Improbability pattern**

In English, describing someone as lucky or unlucky implies repeated pattern of positive/negative improbable occurrences affecting the person when luckiness or unluckiness is attributed to person character in general.

But someone or something can also be called lucky or unlucky just from a single improbable occurrence. E.g. Someone who just won the lottery is *lucky*. Someone who was pushed on accident and dropped food was *unlucky*.

What about other languages? Is pattern required for *unluckiness*?

**3. Scale of improbability or event**

In German, negation of noun *luck* = *das Unglück* is used only for serious misfortunes. For dropping food, one would use *das Pech*.

Similarly, different words could also be used to express measurable difference in improbability (probability of recurrence), e.g. *Guillaume Le Gentil was unlucky to miss transit of Venus two times because it would not occur again in his lifetime.* vs dropping food example

Do you know of the other languages in which those differences are specifically expressed by using other words, declension or otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with some of the assumptions, but maybe you can revise your theory. There are at least two separate semantic issues, positivity, and the ontology of luck. I think that "luck" is by default positive, but it can be negative in some contexts – which means, I conclude, that "luck" is neutral. In a statement like "With any luck, we'll get there before they leave" suggests that we *want* to get there before they leave. In a statement like "With my luck, they'll leave before we get there" still suggests that we want to get there before they leave, however with added "my" it adds a belief that the speaker doesn't have any luck. You can compare "luck" and "fortune", where the latter more strongly tends to be positive.

The ontological question is a complex non-linguistic matter, an answer to the question "the outcome was thus because of ___". Generally speaking, this is a personal, philosophical matter – you can attribute outcomes to supernatural causes, metaphysical randomness (if there is such a thing), factors that you don't know about or can't control, and so on. The word "blessing" is about supernatural causes, but that is a cultural fact and not a strictly linguistic fact. Positive and negative (im)probability is one ontology of "luck", but that's ideological and not linguistic.

Comment: Regarding the positivity issue - that is exactly my point about English language. In English the word "luck" is not consistently positive, like in most other European languages. So I am interested if there are other languages like this. Maybe I did not make it clear, I will try to revise that point.

Comment: Ontological point of view is very nice, I will add it to my question.

Comment: +1 for answers to both questions. Be sure to note that _Fate_ can also be involved. In Terry Pratchett's Discworld® novels, both Fate and "The Lady" (it's .. um .. bad luck to say Her name; Pratchett says "just think of her as the waitress at the Last Chance Saloon") are gods who play games with humans for fun. The novel _Interesting Times_ is framed as a game between these two gods. The luck that the main character gets can be described as either good or bad, depending on the viewpoint.